# TabStop on JTextPane does not work

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to redefine the size of tab that will be displayed on JTextPane.
The fist tab is displayed in the right size (the one I redefined) but the second consecutive displayed in a different size (more like a blank).I have tried to declare more than one TabStop with a different alignment, but still the same result.

I extended the DefaultStyledDocument class because I'm using it color same words, so I the tabs definition is in it.

```
public class KeywordStyledDocument extends DefaultStyledDocument{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Style _defaultStyle;
    private AttributeSet sttSet;
    private StyleContext sContext;

    public KeywordStyledDocument(Style defaultStyle, StyleContext sContext_)
    {
        _defaultStyle = defaultStyle;
        sContext = sContext_;
    }

    public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException
    {
        setTabs();
        this.setParagraphAttributes(0, str.length(), sttSet, false);
        super.insertString(offset, str, a);
        refreshDocument();
    }

    private void setTabs()
    {
        TabStop[] tab = new TabStop[1];
        tab[0] = new TabStop(20, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT, TabStop.LEAD_NONE);
        /*
         * tab[1] = new TabStop(50, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT, TabStop.LEAD_NONE);
         * tab[2] = new TabStop(50, TabStop.ALIGN_CENTER, TabStop.LEAD_NONE);
         * tab[3] = new TabStop(50, TabStop.ALIGN_BAR, TabStop.LEAD_NONE);
         */
        TabSet tabset = new TabSet(tab);
        sttSet = sContext.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.TabSet, tabset);

    }

    public void remove(int offs, int len) throws BadLocationException
    {
        super.remove(offs, len);
        refreshDocument();
    }

    private synchronized void refreshDocument() throws BadLocationException
    {
        String text = getText(0, getLength());
        final List<HiliteWord> list = processWords(text);

        setCharacterAttributes(0, text.length(), _defaultStyle, true);
        for (HiliteWord word : list)
        {
            StyleConstants.setForeground(_defaultStyle, word.getColor());
            setCharacterAttributes(word.getPosition(), word.getWord().length(), _defaultStyle, true);
        }
    }

    private static List<HiliteWord> processWords(String content)
    {
        List<HiliteWord> hiliteWords = new ArrayList<HiliteWord>();
        int startPos = 0, endPos = 0;
        char[] data = content.toCharArray();
        String newWord = "";

        for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++)
        {
            if(data[index] == '<')
            {
                if(data[index + 1] == '/')
                {
                    startPos = index + 2;
                    hiliteWords.add(new HiliteWord("</", index, Color.BLUE));
                }else
                {
                    startPos = index + 1;
                    hiliteWords.add(new HiliteWord("<", index, Color.BLUE));
                }
            }

            if(data[index] == '>')
            {
                hiliteWords.add(new HiliteWord(">", index, Color.BLUE));

                endPos = index;
                newWord = content.substring(startPos, endPos);
            }

            if(!newWord.equals(""))
            {
                hiliteWords.add(new HiliteWord(newWord, startPos, Color.RED));
                newWord = "";
            }
        }
        return hiliteWords;
    }}
```

Calling the text formatter with a text:

```
private void createTabs() throws BadLocationException
{
    for (LRT057Data data : GUI.getArrayOfLRT057())
    {
         JEditorPane editorPane=new JEditorPane();
            editorPane.setEditorKit(new XMLEditorKit());

        KeywordStyledDocument ksd;
        StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        Style style = sc.addStyle("ConstantWidth", null);

        ksd = new KeywordStyledDocument(style, sc);
        ksd.insertString(0, "\tOne Tab\nNo Tab\n\t\tTwo Tabs\n\t\t\tThree Tabs", style);

        JTextPane pane = new JTextPane(ksd);     
        pane.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12));

        JComponent panel = new JScrollPane(pane);
        panel.setAutoscrolls(true);
        listener.addKeyAdapter(pane);
        tabs.addTab(data.getSystemName(), panel);
    }
}
```

result:

[not expected reslt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rkZW.png)

please help.

The problem was solved.
I understood the Tabstop in wrong way.
In order to use tab after tab, the thing needed is to add a few members into tab list each in needed distance from the margin.

Thank you RealSkeptic.

Comment: You seem to be creating only one `TabStop`. Have you read the documentation of [`TabSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/TabSet.html) and [`TabStop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/TabStop.html)?

Comment: I have tried to add a few, with different alignment, and it did not work (you can see the commented out code), that's why I asked here.

Comment: The alignment is not important. But did you read the fact that the number in the tab stop is the distance from the left margin? That is, each tab stop has to have a different number?

Comment: As I have read in documentation:public TabStop(float pos,
       int align,
       int leader)
Creates a tab with the specified position pos, alignment align and leader leader.

Comment: Yes, and the position is relative to the left margin. So why were all the tabs you added on the same position?

Comment: I have some structure in a sting, that have tabs, that go one after another (it's an indentation). As a default tab takes 8 bytes, and it looks bad when I have for example 4 consecutive tabs, indentation of 8*4 bytes. I want to minimize the indentation of a tab (for 2 bytes for example), and that's the way I found to do that

Comment: But why two tabs in the same exact position (position 50)? Why not one tab at 50, one at 100, one at 150, one at 200? If all the tabs are in the same place it's like you don't have more than one tab. I think you simply don't understand what "position" means. It doesn't mean "how far from the previous tab", it means "how far from the left side".

Comment: Yea, now I got it (I thought it meant position from the previous). Thank you your suggestion worked.

Comment: @Marat if you have solved it, please write an answer to your question - this is actually encouraged: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer